# What's the different between 'docker stop' and 'docker kill -s term'

Tags: docker

According to the docs:

- `docker stop <containerName>` will send a `SIGTERM` to the main process inside the container
- `docker kill -s <signal> <containerName>` will send an arbitrary signal to the main process inside the container.

This suggests to me that `docker stop` is equivalent to `docker kill -s term`.

However, that's not the case. When I use `docker kill -s term`, my application receives a SIGTERM and exits gracefully. But when I use `docker stop`, my application receives no signals, and after the 10-second timeout Docker will force kill the process.

What could explain this different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the docs are incomplete in this area. `docker stop` won't always send a `SIGTERM`. If there is a different 'stop signal' configured in the image metadata, it will send that signal instead.

In my case, the parent image I had built upon contained this line in its Dockerfile:

```
STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT
```

So Docker would send a `SIGQUIT` instead of a `SIGTERM` whenever you call stop.